# Fix/offset tiles coordinates on leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, arcgis

I downloaded some tiles from ArcGIS.Imagery with SAS Planet
The tiles is in folders like

```
ArcGIS.Imagery/z2/0/x1/0/y2.jpg
```

And I use this TileLayer to display it on leaflet.

```
  L.TileLayer.customTiles = L.TileLayer.extend({
            getTileUrl: function (t) {
                console.log('coords', t);
                z = t.z,
                    x = t.x,
                    y = t.y,
                    z0 = t.z,
                    x0 = Math.floor(t.x / 1024),
                    x1 = Math.floor(t.x % 1024),
                    y0 = Math.floor(t.y / 1024),
                    y1 = Math.floor(t.y % 1024)

                const d = `ArcGIS.Imagery/z${z0}/${x0}/x${x1}/${y0}/y${y1}.jpg`;
                console.log('d', d);
                return d;
            }
        });
        L.tileLayer.customTiles = function () {
            return new L.TileLayer.customTiles();
        }
        L.tileLayer.customTiles().addTo(map);
```

But it looks like there is wrong coordinates. Here is what I got as a result. Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Where did you download those tiles from, *exactly*? Are they from any documented & well-known service?

Comment: @IvanSanchez with SAS Planet

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's already been replied at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341108/sas-planet-cached-tiles-for-use-in-leaflet-map